# the button hanging on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

my gui app doesn't answer when I click the `connect` button. actually, the button working. its function gets the data from serial and converts a list form as I want (and just for checking prints terminal). but when data comes from serial and converting split data list, at the same time I want to click the `start listing data` button and show datas in graphs and labels that I have (but I delete their code now, just added print in `StartListing()` function for representing them.)

is it because of threat? `while` keep going so python can't do anything else? how can I fix it? all I can think of is to gather all the functions under a single function and get the job done with a single button. but that's not very nice either.

here is the pic if I couldn't explain. the `connect` button stays like this and then the program doesn't allow to click anywhere.
[image]

```
from tkinter import *
import time 
from tkinter import ttk 
import serial


root = Tk()

root.title("app")
root.geometry("500x500")
root.configure(bg="#0059aa")


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
global datas
datas = []

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#seri port 

seriPortOuter = LabelFrame(root,text=u"SERIAL PORT",border=3, width=170,height=210)
seriPortOuter.pack()
global text1
text1= Label(seriPortOuter,text=u"get connection", width=14, 
                    font=("Helvetica",10),
                    fg="white", bg="red")
text1.place(x=3,y=5)

text2= Label(seriPortOuter,text="COM Port: ", width=8, 
                    font=("Helvetica",10))
text2.place(x=1,y=30)

portList = ["COM3", "COM5", "COM8",
          "COM7", "Option5", "Option6"]
port = StringVar()
portCombo = ttk.Combobox(seriPortOuter, textvariable=port ,values = portList, width=10)
portCombo.set("pick port") 
portCombo.place(x=70,y=30)

text3= Label(seriPortOuter,text=u"Baud: ", width=4, 
                    font=("Helvetica",10))
text3.place(x=1,y=55)
speedList = ["19200","157600",
          "74880", "115200"]
speed = IntVar()
speedCombo = ttk.Combobox(seriPortOuter, textvariable=speed , values = speedList, width=10)
speedCombo.set("pick baud") 
speedCombo.place(x=70,y=55)

def portConnect():
    ser = serial.Serial()
    ser.port = port.get()
    ser.baudrate = int(speed.get())
    ser.setDTR(False)
    ser.setRTS(False)

    ser.open()
    if ser.isOpen():
        print("open")
        global text1
        text1['background'] = "green"
        text1.configure(text="connected")

        while ser.isOpen(): # True
            global datas 
            datas.clear()
            pureData = ser.readline()  
            convertedData = pureData.decode('UTF-8')
            convertedData = convertedData.replace("<"," ")
            convertedData = convertedData.replace(">"," ")
            convertedData = convertedData.split(",")
            datas = convertedData

            print(datas)

            time.sleep(2.0)

global x 
x = 0
def StartListing():
    global x
    root.after(2000,StartListing)
    x = x +1
    print(x)


portConnectButton = Button(seriPortOuter, text=u"connect",command=portConnect, width=19)
portConnectButton.place(x=10,y=85)

portConnectButton = Button(seriPortOuter, text=u"start listing data", command=StartListing, width=19)
portConnectButton.place(x=10,y=125)   

portConnectButton = Button(seriPortOuter, text=u"stop listing", width=19)
portConnectButton.place(x=10,y=155)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think `root.after(2000,StartListing)` causes the button to 'hang'. The line probably is to go to the function again (it's a loop of statements that don't do anything but switch from one line to another) - the next two lines aren't executed because of it. Bring `root.after(2000,StartListing)` below `print(x)`.

Comment: i can't even run their function so they cause a problem.  also did it but didn't work. @TheAmateurCoder